# Как получить содержимое файла с другого сайта?

Tags: javascript

Такая проблема:
Я написал userscript для сайта. В нём мне необходимо получить из другого сайта содержимое файла "[https://сайт/answ.txt](https://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/answ.txt)". Но не получается никак это сделать.
Вот одна из многочисленных попыток это сделать

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "https://site/answ.txt", true);
x.onload = function (x) {
    var x = this.responseText;
    alert(x);
}
x.send();
```

читал эту статью http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain. Но всё равно ничего не получилось

Comment: Если вам другой сайт запрещает получать информацию, то вы сможете это сделать только через прокси сервер.

Comment: ну я проверил, через браузер я могу получить его содержимое, и в fiddler создавал запрос и всё успешно

Comment: В браузере отдельно конечно откроется, но в js получить не получится, если нет нужных заголовков CORS на там конце. Как у вас в fiddler вышло не знаю, случайно не на fiddler файл лежит?)

Comment: нет, на бесплатном хостинге

Comment: в хроме во вкладке сеть (режим разработчика) такая надпись появляется "Provisional headers are shown"

Comment: Ну вы хоть сайт покажите, на котором данные лежат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым. При отправке запроса на другой домен, в целях обеспечения безопасности, cors (механизм безопасности) блокирует ответ если в нём не содержится заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (вместо звезды может находиться наш сайт, с которого отправлялся запрос). Это можно сделать, добавив в файл .htaccess  в корне сайта такие строки:

`Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" 
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization`

Во второй строке указываем разрешённые методы, в первой место * сайт, с которого разрешены запросы.

Comment: Простым в плане что Вам много кода менять не пришлось? CORS это не так то уж просто, если разложить все по полочкам. И я предполагаю что если бы Вы в вопросе указали что сайт с которого вы хотите получить файл принадлежит Вам, то Вам бы сразу ответили про отсутствие заголовка и что куда добавить :)